# Hyperbolicity of Convection-Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

So I was studying the numerical analysis of Convection-Diffusion equation. It said that it's a Hyperbolic equation in this form
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+div(u\beta)+\sigma u=0$$
where
$$\beta=\mbox{Velocity Field ,} \sigma=\mbox{Absorption coeffecient}$$

My question is how it is Hyperbolic? $B^2-4AC=0$, then how are we saying its Hyperbolic?

Reference: Numerical Solution of PDE using FEM, Claes Johnson, Pg: 168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classification you're using is only valid for *second-order* equations and does not apply to *first-order* equations such as the one you're considering.  Take a look at [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) in the section on hyperbolic systems and conservation laws.  Your equation is of this form where the "system" is degenerate in the sense that $s=1$ (in wikipedia's notation), i.e. the equation is scalar.  Nevertheless, if you apply the definition used there you will find that your problem is hyperbolic.